# Why can't I use the member method to init an instance?

Tags: javascript

I met an issue of JavaScript constructor, which seems to be some basic knowledge about JavaScript. However, I didn't know it. Could some one help me out?

I want to create an instance of Circle. Circle constructor looks like following:

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
   var _radius;
   // An exception is thrown at using member method setRadius.
   this.setRadius(radius);

   this.setRadius = function(value) {
      _radius = value;
   };
};
var circle = new Circle(5);
```

An exception is thrown out saying that this.setRadius is undefined. I don't get what's going wrong here. Does the exception happen because the definition of setRadius is after its invocation? If I move setRadius's definition ahead of its invocation, everything goes fine.

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
   var _radius;
   this.setRadius = function(value) {
      _radius = value;
   };

   this.setRadius(radius);
};
```

If setRadius is defined in the prototype, there is no problem at all.

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
   this.radius;
   // It's OK to use the method on the prototype chain.
   this.setRadius(radius);
};

Circle.prototype.setRadius = function(value) {
   this.radius = value;
};
```

And I'm pretty sure a member method is able to use another member method which is defined after it. The following codes work pretty well.

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
   var _radius = radius;

   this.enlarge = function(per) {
      this.setRadius(_radius*per);
   };

   this.setRadius = function(value) {
      _radius = value;
   };
};
var circle = new Circle(5);
circle.enlarge(1.1);
```

So at creating the instance, why can't I use a member method? Javascript is an interpretation language. Hence, when I start new instance, the constructor Function is already interpreted and generated.  Why is its member method still undefined?

Comment: I would imagine you have answered your own question. Javascript is sequential in its execution so when the function Circle is called `this.setRadius(radius);` is undefined **because the definition of setRadius is after its invocation**.  In your 3rd example you are defining functions rather than calling them immediately so there is no issue there.  Everything in javascript is an object, even your constructor function. So you are basically trying to run a function on an object where the function has been defined yet. (I could be wrong but that would be my understanding of it)

Comment: You need to understand that the order of assignments matter, especially in JavaScript. If you call `this.setRadius()` before setting `this.setRadius` to something, `this.setRadius` will be undefined. Using the `prototype` approach will make the JavaScript VM look through the prototype chain. You have basically answered your own question. Now learn from what you wrote yourself. :) And @user3455363 is simply wrong! The `this` reference inside a function being called as a constructor points to the object being created - not the `window`!

Answer (score 0):

Place the setRadius before calling it.

```
var Circle = function(radius) {
   var _radius;


   this.setRadius = function(value) {
      _radius = value;
   };

   // An exception is thrown at using member method setRadius.
   this.setRadius(radius);
};

var circle = new Circle(5);
```

While calling the pseudo class Circle, as per your statement first it set a local variable _radius, then call the setRadius of the same instance, which is undefined at the moment.